# What does "there" refer to?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2* (2011), Harry get a hold on Ressurection stone, then he sees
4 dead people standing near him:

> James: You're nearly **there**, son.
>
> Harry: I'm sorry. I never wanted any of you to die for me.

What does "there" refer to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"There" likely refers to the completion of his journey into the woods to be killed by Voldemort in order to allow Voldemort to die. Harry is journeying to be caught by Voldemort and to deliberately be killed, as he is a Horcrux of Voldemort's (albeit an accidental one), and James's words are likely words of encouragement to not give up. There was no other way to kill Voldemort; his soul would have lived on in Harry if Harry had not died. **Thus, "there" refers to Harry's ultimate death that comes soon after.**